# THREE.js in node.js environment

Tags: node.js, three.js, collision-detection

Due to making some simple multiplayer game, I have chosen THREE.js for implementing graphics at browser side. At the browser everything works fine.

Then I thought:
Server have to check out most of user actions. So I WILL need to have world copy on a server, interact it with users and then give it's state back to users.

So, As the good piece of code had been written for client side - I just made it node.js compatible and moved on. (Good collision detection, which could use `object.geometry` - is what I wanted so bad)

As a result, collision detection code stopped working. On the server side Raycaster exits on 
the string

```
    } else if ( object instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

        var geometry = object.geometry;

        // Checking boundingSphere distance to ray

        if ( geometry.boundingSphere === null ) geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

        sphere.copy( geometry.boundingSphere );
        sphere.applyMatrix4( object.matrixWorld );

        if ( raycaster.ray.isIntersectionSphere( sphere ) === false ) {
            return intersects; // _HERE_

        }
```

And that happens, because `object.matrixWorld` Is **Identity** matrix.
But object initialization is made. `mesh.position` and `mesh.rotation` are identical on server and client( in browser, raycaster works as a charm);

I thinking, that, `object.matrixWorld` would update somewhere in `renderer.render(self.three_scene, self.camera);`. But of course, that's not what I want to do at server side.

So the question is: How to make `object.matrixWorld` update in each simulation tick on the server-side?

Or, maybe advice, if there's some other way to get something simular to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey.

That was simple.

`renderer.render` updates matrices of the whole scene recursively. The entrance of the recursion is `updateMatrixWorld()` function of Object3D instance.

So, before we use Raycaster on the server-side we should call this method for each mesh in collidable meshes list.

Comment: Was struggling with this for good two hours "why does my raycaster works locally, but not on server side?" Big thanks, this makes it work on server side now too :)